# "+" symbol removed from $_GET[''] variable passed by dynamic url

Tags: php, mysqli, get

I am trying to check if a hash value from a dynamic url and a hash value from a mysql select statement are equal to verify a user's account to register them on my site. The "+" symbol in the hash passed by the dynamic url to a GET variable seems to have gone missing and been replaced with a space. Is there anyway I can code this so that that will not happen?

As far as I know the "+" symbol is a valid character to be used in a dynamic url.

Here is my code

```
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $un, $password, $dbname);
if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "SELECT hash FROM login WHERE username = '$username'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
$verify = $row["hash"];
}
} else {
echo "0 results";
echo "Error Selecting record: " . $conn->error;
}

echo $username;
echo $hash;
if ($verify == $hash ){
echo "It works!";

$sql = "UPDATE login SET active = 1 WHERE username = '$username'";
}
if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
echo "Record updated successfully";
} else {
echo  $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In PHP, `+` in a query string parameter (e.g. `foo=bar+bat`) is substituted with a space. You need to [URL encode](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) your query string to replace that `+` with a `%2B` in order to get an actual plus through.